# Can I replace a C# method with another with the same name and signature?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a following situation. Some .Net runtime method doesn't work very well and I need to craft a workaround. Like there's `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` which sometimes returns a closed reader object and I want to have code like this:

```
 SqlDataReader MyExecuteReader( this SqlCommand command )
 {
     var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
     if( reader.IsClosed() ) {
        throw new ClosedReaderReturnedException();
     }
     return reader;
 }
```

This would be just fine except I now need to change all the code that calls `ExecuteReader()` so that it now calls `MyExecuteReader()` and it makes maintenance harder.

Is there a way to somehow declare that whenever any of my code wants `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` called `MyExecuteReader()` is called instead? Effectively is it possible to replace an existing method with another one having exactly the same signature and the same name?

Comment: sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Is it possible to have a extension method with some extra optional parameters to make it look like an overload? I am sorry, I am asking question instead of answering it.

Comment: its possibly with profiling api or something really hacky.  There is this one here from couple years ago http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer buts is really hacky

Comment: Using the Sealed SqlCommand makes changes hard. Instead you could use an interface, implementing the methods of SqlCommand. You can the either implement forwarding to SqlCommand in a derived class or using dynamicproxy for that. If this is legacy code, I think you're out of luck

Comment: @Marwijn This sounds similar to my answer below, it seems like one of the 'cleanest' options.

Comment: Of course, that replacement process might replace your reference to the original function inside your replacement method. Hello, recursive stack overflow!

Comment: @gt Completely agree, Hadn't seen your answer yet, wouldn't have comment if I had seen it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is similar to problems when trying to unit test code using mocks.

One way round it is to replace the use of `SqlCommand` in code with an object implementing an interface with the `ExecuteReader` method on it. You can then more easily substitute the object, perhaps using a factory pattern.

So you would replace code like this:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query))
{
    command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

with:

```
var sqlCommandFactory = new SqlCommandFactory();
using (ISqlCommand command = sqlCommandFactory.CreateSqlCommand(query))
{
    command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Firstly defining an interface which contains the methods you want to substitute:

```
public interface ISqlCommand
{
    SqlDataReader ExecuteReader();

    // further interface methods here...
}
```

Then create a factory, which uses the same signature as the `SqlCommand` constructor:

```
internal class SqlCommandFactory
{
    bool _useMyClass = true;

    public ISqlCommand CreateSqlCommand(string query)
    {
        if (_useMyClass)
        {
            return new MySqlCommand(query);
        }
        else
        {
            return new SqlCommandWrapper(query);
        }
    }
}
```

You then write your substitute code in the `MySqlCommand` class:

```
public MySqlCommand : ISqlCommand
{
    public SqlDataReader ExecuteReader()
    {
        // your new code here
    }
}
```

As the .NET `SqlCommand` class obviously does not implement the new `ISqlCommand` interface, create a wrapper class which does this:

```
public SqlCommandWrapper : ISqlCommand
{
    SqlCommand _sqlCommand;

    public SqlCommandWrapper(string query)
    {
        _sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query);
    }

    public SqlDataReader ExecuteReader()
    {
        _sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

A little extra work, but the benefits of this method are that you can change the implementation to whatever you want, including for unit testing (by passing in a mock factory to your code).

The extra work should be a one-off, and preserves the name and original method signature as requested. This should make your code look more familiar and easier to understand (compared to custom/extension methods), especially once you (or your team) gets used to this well-known pattern.

Answer (score 12):

No, what you want is not supported. If the class is not sealed, and the method is not static, you could inherit the class with the same name in a different namespace and change the `using`, and override the method. But that is a limited solution.

Your best option would be to implement standart extension method with a different name, and replace all usages. This might seems like a lot of work in a large code base, and might be prone to human errors down the road - someone adding new call to the original method. However, the one time cost is offset by the fact that your code now is explicit that you have made modifications to the behavior; and you can guard against human errors by writing your own custom FxCop rule (or whatever static analysis tool you are running regularly).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could use a library like Cecil to rewrite the IL like done here: http://plaureano.blogspot.dk/2011/05/introduction-to-il-rewriting-with-cecil.html?m=1

But I do believe that it is way better to rewrite your code, so it is clear to anyone else (and yourself later) who might read your code, what is going on :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to do that. It's going to confuse everybody who reads the code.

However, I believe it can't be done, but not in any nice or guaranteed-to-be-supported-for-long way. Back in the old days we could inject functions instead of DLL-exported functions. Antivirus programs used this technique.

Apparently, someone managed to figure out how to [inject .NET methods.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer)

Keep in mind this will probably be a lot more trouble than it's worth. You'll have to QA extensively on all sorts of platforms with all sorts of extra software installed (one kind of antivirus might break your code). So really, just do what everybody else suggested - create your extension method and just search-and-replace your entire code base.

Comment: Not only injecting methods on the fly is going to be too much effort, and can break at any point in time, but if it works, it will work only for full trust code executions. CAS will prevent anything like that in medium or low trust sandboxes.

Comment: Which is why I recommended NOT doing that.